# Trying to add column with a value from filter in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a table with rows that show a list of calls, there are multiple calls from the same client in some days, I want to show a common id in a new column where all calls from a client that happened in the same day should show the id of the first call from that client that day that lasted more than 15 seconds. I'm trying the next code where previus step's name is "Máximo insertado"

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Máximo insertado", "EventoID", each List.Min(List.Select(#"Máximo insertado"[Call_ID], each #"Máximo insertado"[Cliente] = [Cliente] and Number.RoundDown(#"Máximo insertado"[Date],0) = Number.RoundDown([Date],0) and #"Máximo insertado"[Duration] >= 15)))
```

I belive that my mistake is that I'm not using List.Select properly, but I have not been able to find an example of it that helps

Edit: This is a sample of the table, the last column is the one i'm trying to add.

| Call_ID | Date | Cliente | Duration | EventoID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 73754 | 15/06/2022 09:00:36 | 25441919 | 0 | 73754 |
| 75614 | 15/06/2022 11:16:00 | 40549143 | 36 | 75614 |
| 75790 | 15/06/2022 11:22:15 | 40549143 | 107 | 75614 |
| 75805 | 15/06/2022 11:50:23 | 40549143 | 95 | 75614 |
| 75931 | 15/06/2022 13:25:50 | 55559355 | 247 | 75931 |
| 76280 | 15/06/2022 14:53:25 | 52409455 | 2 | 76387 |
| 76387 | 15/06/2022 15:10:12 | 52409455 | 37 | 76387 |
| 76555 | 16/06/2022 10:15:13 | 52409455 | 33 | 76555 |

Comment: edit your question to post your sample input data and desired output

Comment: I edited the question, but it is still closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn( #"Máximo insertado" ,"EventoID",(i)=>
     try
         Table.Sort(
             Table.SelectRows(#"Máximo insertado", each 
                 [Cliente]=i[Cliente] and
                 Date.From(i[Date]) = Date.From([Date])
                 and [Duration] >= 15
             )
         ,{{"Date", Order.Ascending}})
     {0}[Call_ID]
     otherwise i[Call_ID]
 )
```

Comment: I still have a lot to learn, and I don't seem to understand what the "(i)=>" part does, can you explain it to me?

Comment: using (i)=> we can refer to value of the row as i[column] and all rows as [column], so we can filter the larger table for the value of the row

Comment: So it's like using "each" but assingning the row to a variable. Thank you